# Double integration over a general region

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

$\iint x^2 +2y$ bound by $y=x$ $y=x^3$  $x \geq 0$

this is either a type I or type II since the bounds are already nicely given for a type I, I integrated it as a type I:

Finding the bounds:

$x^3=x \to x^3-x=0 \to x(x^{2}-1)= 0 \to x=0, x=\pm1$

Since $-1\lt 0$ my bounds for $x$ are $[0,1]$ and since $x \gt x^3$, $x$ is my upper bound for dy.

$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{x^3}^{x} x^2+2y$ $dydx$

$\int_{x^3}^{x}$ $x^2+y^2$ $\Big\vert_{x}^{x3}$dy $=$ $(2x^2) - (-x^2+x^6)$

$\int_{0}^{1} 3x^2+x^6 dx=$ $x^{3}+\frac{1}{7}x^7 \Big\vert_{0}^{1} \to 1 -\frac{1}{7}$ $=\frac{6}{7}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $x^3\lt x$ in the interval $(0,1)$.  (A picture always helps in this kind of problem.)

So $y$ travels from $y=x^3$ to $y=x$.

One can see without checking details that the answer $-\frac{4}{21}$ cannot be right. Your integrand is positive in the region, so the answer must be positive.

Comment: I corrected my mistakes. Does this look correct?

Comment: You are integrating $x^2+2y$ with respect to $y$. The result should be $x^2y+y^2$. (You got $x^2+y^2$.) Now plug in the limits carefully, and integrate again.